# MySQL Filter records to adding a specific date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i want to filter records to adding dates. This code has mistake, i know but how can i filter records?

```
select * from `UserAdTypes`
inner join `Ads` on `Ads.id` = `UserAdTypes`.`ad_id`
inner join `AdEducationPrices` on `AdEducationPrices`.`ad_id` = `Ads`.`id`
inner join `UserAds` on `UserAds`.`ad_id` = `Ads.id`
inner join `AdTimes` on `AdTimes`.`id` = `UserAdTypes`.`times_type`
left join `AdMedias` on `AdMedias`.`ad_id` = `Ads`.`id`
where `Ads`.`is_publish` = 1 and `UserAds`.`is_purchased` = 1 and 
      `UserAdTypes`.`is_purchased` = 1 and `UserAdTypes`.`adtype_id` = 3 
and DATE_ADD( STR_TO_DATE( `UserAdTypes`.`started_at`,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) , INTERVAL `UserAdTypes`.`times` `AdTimes`.`tag` ) >= CURDATE() )
and DATE_ADD( STR_TO_DATE( `UserAds`.`started_at`,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) , INTERVAL `UserAds`.`times` `AdTimes`.`tag` ) >= CURDATE() )
orderby Rand() limit 1
```

[image: My Tables]

Comment: Why are you using `STR_TO_DATE()` conversions on fields that are already in an appropriate datetime format? Also it is not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve.  can you explain what you believe your query is doing?

Comment: I found this code and i tried. You right but i can't do :(

Comment: Are you saying that you posted somebody else's code and do not know what it actually does?

Comment: No, i used only this code `DATE_ADD( STR_TO_DATE( `UserAds`.`started_at`,  '%d/%m/%Y' ) , INTERVAL `UserAds`.`times` `AdTimes`.`tag` ) >= CURDATE() )`